# office365 SMTP cannot connect

Tags: smtp

[image: Global Configuration]

I'm trying to use SMTP with Office365 settings but I keep getting SMTP cannot connect.    I attach a screenshot of my settings.

With my host you have to allow SMTP to be sent which I have done.

When I send a test mail it just says "mail cannot be sent" quick quickly.

Saving takes long and I get this fantastic message

```
Notice
The following from address failed: root@localhost : MAIL FROM command failed,000030020000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140F9F8F2000F01F1F001432, 20.50032:140F9F8F9017F01F07000000, 0.35180:1F000130, 255.23226:35230000, 255.27962:7A000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:21000000, 0.35250:1F001336, 1.36674:0A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:02000000, 1.44866:CE000000, 1.36674:32000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:D3000000, 1.44866:01000000, 16.55847:3A010000, 17.43559:0000000078030000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140F9F8F2000101068000000, 20.50032:140F9F8F9017000008240000, 0.35180:6D000000, 255.23226:0A000C80, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:32000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.27745:3E240000, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:6F240000, 0.38698:05000780, 0.37692:01000000, 0.37948:19000010, 5.33852:00000000534D545000000010, 7.36354:010000000000010902000010, 4.56248:DC040000, 7.40748:010000000000010B02000010, 7.57132:000000000000000011000010, 1.63016:32000000, 4.39640:DC040000, 8.45434:7CDFA38FCC22984DA98ED3CA8D3C70CF02000010, 1.46798:04000000, 5.10786:0000000031352E32302E333939392E3033323A4C4F32503236354D42323839333A32633063326639342D653966652D343561642D613937312D6330356138326563633766373A323031320010, 7.51330:0C32946637F9D8081E000010, 0.39570:02000010, 1.55954:0A000000, 0.49266:04000000, 1.33010:0A000000, 2.54258:00000000, 0.40002:07000000, 1.56562:00000000, 1.64146:32000000, 1.33010:32000000, 2.54258:DC040000, 255.1750:0A006136, 255.31418:99260000, 0.22753:BA000000, 255.21817:DC040000, 0.64418:CA260000, 4.39842:DC040000, 0.41586:03000336, 4.60547:DC040000, 0.21966:C4000000, 4.30158:DC040000 [Hostname=LO2P265MB2893.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] 250 2.1.0 Sender OK ,000,SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: 000030020000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140F9F8F2000F01F1F001432, 20.50032:140F9F8F9017F01F07000000, 0.35180:1F000130, 255.23226:35230000, 255.27962:7A000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:21000000, 0.35250:1F001336, 1.36674:0A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:02000000, 1.44866:CE000000, 1.36674:32000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:D3000000, 1.44866:01000000, 16.55847:3A010000, 17.43559:0000000078030000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140F9F8F2000101068000000, 20.50032:140F9F8F9017000008240000, 0.35180:6D000000, 255.23226:0A000C80, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:32000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.27745:3E240000, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:6F240000, 0.38698:05000780, 0.37692:01000000, 0.37948:19000010, 5.33852:00000000534D545000000010, 7.36354:010000000000010902000010, 4.56248:DC040000, 7.40748:010000000000010B02000010, 7.57132:000000000000000011000010, 1.63016:32000000, 4.39640:DC040000, 8.45434:7CDFA38FCC22984DA98ED3CA8D3C70CF02000010, 1.46798:04000000, 5.10786:0000000031352E32302E333939392E3033323A4C4F32503236354D42323839333A32633063326639342D653966652D343561642D613937312D6330356138326563633766373A323031320010, 7.51330:0C32946637F9D8081E000010, 0.39570:02000010, 1.55954:0A000000, 0.49266:04000000, 1.33010:0A000000, 2.54258:00000000, 0.40002:07000000, 1.56562:00000000, 1.64146:32000000, 1.33010:32000000, 2.54258:DC040000, 255.1750:0A006136, 255.31418:99260000, 0.22753:BA000000, 255.21817:DC040000, 0.64418:CA260000, 4.39842:DC040000, 0.41586:03000336, 4.60547:DC040000, 0.21966:C4000000, 4.30158:DC040000 [Hostname=LO2P265MB2893.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] 250 2.1.0 Sender OK SMTP code: 000SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: 000030020000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140F9F8F2000F01F1F001432, 20.50032:140F9F8F9017F01F07000000, 0.35180:1F000130, 255.23226:35230000, 255.27962:7A000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:21000000, 0.35250:1F001336, 1.36674:0A000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:02000000, 1.44866:CE000000, 1.36674:32000000, 1.61250:00000000, 1.45378:D3000000, 1.44866:01000000, 16.55847:3A010000, 17.43559:0000000078030000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140F9F8F2000101068000000, 20.50032:140F9F8F9017000008240000, 0.35180:6D000000, 255.23226:0A000C80, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:32000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.27745:3E240000, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:6F240000, 0.38698:05000780, 0.37692:01000000, 0.37948:19000010, 5.33852:00000000534D545000000010, 7.36354:010000000000010902000010, 4.56248:DC040000, 7.40748:010000000000010B02000010, 7.57132:000000000000000011000010, 1.63016:32000000, 4.39640:DC040000, 8.45434:7CDFA38FCC22984DA98ED3CA8D3C70CF02000010, 1.46798:04000000, 5.10786:0000000031352E32302E333939392E3033323A4C4F32503236354D42323839333A32633063326639342D653966652D343561642D613937312D6330356138326563633766373A323031320010, 7.51330:0C32946637F9D8081E000010, 0.39570:02000010, 1.55954:0A000000, 0.49266:04000000, 1.33010:0A000000, 2.54258:00000000, 0.40002:07000000, 1.56562:00000000, 1.64146:32000000, 1.33010:32000000, 2.54258:DC040000, 255.1750:0A006136, 255.31418:99260000, 0.22753:BA000000, 255.21817:DC040000, 0.64418:CA260000, 4.39842:DC040000, 0.41586:03000336, 4.60547:DC040000, 0.21966:C4000000, 4.30158:DC040000 [Hostname=LO2P265MB2893.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] 250 2.1.0 Sender OK SMTP code: 000
```

Comment: Anyone know how to format that stupidly long error message on here?

Comment: I started to edit your error message to make it vertical (with quote block formatting - which is generally used for conveying error responses), but it just makes the page unattractively long.  Let's leave the error message format as it is.  There isn't much value in bloating the page with its rambling details.  The few people that want to read the full message will have to suffer the horizontal scrolling.  I think it is the best we can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to my host and they turned on some settings when they did an update to the server.  My server is based on Litespeed Webserver so it could have been that.  Or possibly they updated the OpenSSL feature because I saw that mentioned in the documentation.

Lesson to learn: ask your host

Comment: ...let's get your host to have a representative join JSE, then they can articulately share their exact action as an answer.  This sharing only serves to help ...well, everyone.  I'm looking forward to speaking about knowledge sharing at Jday USA.

Comment: I've asked them what they did and linked to this post in case they want to share their own answer :)

Comment: They have said that they just ran `yum update` which updated quite a few packages, so it will be hard for them to pinpoint the exact issue.  I would best guess OpenSSL was the issue.